# Making a UIView receive events after showing it (setting hidden = false)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I already tested the solution of setting up the `alpha` property from 0 to 1. However, this seems to be performance intensive operation. 
What I want to do to make the `UIView` receive the touch events after showing it back by setting `hidden = false`

Is there a way to do that? I thought calling `.becomeFirstResponder` would solve this with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The first thing is mention by @wltrup that you have to enable userInteraction property of that view by this:

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

and another is you have to add proper gesture recognizer on that UIView to perform specific events.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I think it might not even related to this, but to the fact the item I am hiding is a scrollView inside a uicollectionviewcell.